# NextGen gallary for WordPress not displaying correcting in chrome

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, nextgen-gallery

The NextGen gallery isn't displaying properly in Chrome, but works fine in firefox. Has anyone found a fix for this problem?

Even the sample page for the gallery display isn't displaying correctly. http://nextgen-gallery.com/gallery-tags/

When you open an image to view it, after moving to a second image, the image moves down a bit and after a few images its sitting below the website, not near the top or in the middle. This is making it fairly unusable.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better Yet:

```
<style type="text/css">

#shDisplay {
    top:15%!important;.
}

</style>
```

Worked for me, and does not have an absolute value, which is better for different sized monitors!!

Answer (score 1):

just use  this in the header of your page :)

it did the job in chrome for me :)

```
<style type="text/css">

#shDisplay {
    top:30px!important;.
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to this discussion i have solved a similar problem (first photo open at the bottom of the page in Chrome and Firefox). But i had to change a .css script a little and to add a rule for "fancybox-wrap" div:

```
<style type="text/css">
#shDisplay {
    top:15%!important;
}
#fancybox-wrap {
    top:5%!important;
}
</style>
```

Thank you!